# Photons and EM Fields

Tags: quantum-field-theory

I started learning the basic ideas of QFT in an intuitive manner ( withouth any math, only with mental videos and pictures ) some days ago, and i'm finding it completely beautiful [ the idea of forgetting the notion of particles is so alleviating ] .

But i have some little doubt and i wondered if you guys could help me figure that out.

**EM Fields**

Pertubations in the electron field [ what we can picture as an electron particle ] , if they are "standing still" in space  , interacts with ( generates and get's influenced by ) an EM field that has only the E component.

Furthermore, pertubations in the electron field that are "moving" with uniformly velocity in space,  interacts with ( generates and get's influenced by ) an EM field that has only the B component.

Finally, pertubations in the electron field that are "accelerating" in space, interacts with ( generates and gets influenced by ) an EM field that has both the E as well as the B component.

**Photons ?**

In this last case, where our charge is accelerating, the idea of photons become really clear, they become the discrete quantum fields that make up in energy the totality of the interacting EM field, and the energy of each chunk is related to the acceleration motion of the charge [ the frequency spectra of the EM wave propagated ] .      Each of those quantum fields that make the EM field can collapse at any given time.

But i'm really in doubt about the relation between photons ( quanta of the EM fields ) and that case where the EM field has only the E component ( or only the B component ) , namely, the case where our pertubation in the electron field is at inertia in space.

Are photons again the quanta of those EM fields ( that happen to have only E component, or only B component ) present , or is the idea of quanta of EM field,namely  photons ,intrinsically related to the idea of accelerating charges ?

Sorry for writing this question on a really layman style and probably ignoring some important aspects, it's just that don't yet know anything close to the math to formalize it. Furthermore, feel free to correct me if i wrote anything that is just intrinsically wrong ( even on the intuitive level ).

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, photons are the quanta of the electromagnetic field.[image]

In this picture, two charges create a disturbance in the EM field (which can also be called the photon field). A virtual photon mediates their repulsion. There is more information [here](http://profmattstrassler.com/articles-and-posts/particle-physics-basics/virtual-particles-what-are-they/).

Comment: Do you know if the photon field specifically at vacuum state, needed some excited electron field to generate it in first place ? Thanks

Comment: @nerdy photon field is everywhere.

Comment: But doesnt it have a cause ? I thought the EM field requires a charged field in order to be created.

Comment: @nerdy that causes an excitation in the photon field.

Comment: Perharps i'm confusing myself. It's just that in Classical Physics, a standing still charge is required for an  electric field ( an EM field ) to be generated.   Does the notion of an electrical field ( EM with no magnetic component ) exist in the quantum realm ?

Comment: Your confusion is natural. A particle is an excitation in a field, this is what a moving charge does. It excites the photon field. @nerdy

Comment: I see, but suppose an excitation is created on the electron field and it remains constant in the state it was created through out a lot of time ( the analogous of being standing still ). Will there be any excitation on the EM field ? Will there be photons ?

Comment: @nerdy: the notion of an electrical field only is not correct in special relativity. If in a frame the field is seen as E only, in another frame (boosted), the field will be a mixture of E and B.